# Creating an html table from multi-dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an html table from a multi-dimensional array with nested objects. I'm trying to make something like this:

[image: nested data from multi-dimensional array]

I need to output the `specs` of the data into a table, with the `key` in col A, and values across. If a key is empty in another product, I want to add a `--`

How do I get the key and value pairs into a table with nested data?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sorfi939399/0ehyc7ud/42/)

```js
const tableHead = document.querySelector('.responsive-table .js-th');
const tableBody = document.querySelector('.responsive-table .js-tb');
const getData = [
  [{
    title: 'title1',
    image: 'https://placehold.it/25x25',
    price: '$55.55',
    specs: {
      weight: '40lbs',
      color: 'yellow',
      available: true
    }
  }],
  [{
    title: 'title2',
    image: 'https://placehold.it/25x25',
    price: '$55.55',
    specs: {
      color: 'red',
      available: false
    }
  }],
  [{
    title: 'title3',
    image: 'https://placehold.it/25x25',
    price: '$55.55',
    specs: {
      available: true
    }
  }]
]

buildTable();
//console.log(getData);

function buildTable() {
  let rows = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
//    console.log(getData[i][0].title)
    let head =
      `
        <th>
          <img src="${getData[i][0].image}" />
          <p>${getData[i][0].title}</p>
          <p>${getData[i][0].price}</p>
        </th>
        `
    tableHead.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', head);
  }
  tableHead.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<th>specs</th>');

  for (var p in getData) {
    for (var k in getData[p]) {
      rows += '<tr><td>' + k + '</td><td>' + getData[p][k] + '</td></tr>'
    }
  }

  tableBody.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', rows);
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="js-th"></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="js-tb"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JSX so I rewrite the header part a little bit but it is basicly the same.

For the specs part I've created a Set (I use Set instead of Array to prevente duplicates) with all specs and then for each spec added a row in your bodyTable.

```js
const tableHead = document.querySelector('.responsive-table .js-th');
const tableBody = document.querySelector('.responsive-table .js-tb');
const getData = [
  [{
    title: 'title1',
    image: 'https://placehold.it/25x25',
    price: '$55.55',
    specs: {
      weight: '40lbs',
      color: 'yellow',
      available: true
    }
  }],
  [{
    title: 'title2',
    image: 'https://placehold.it/25x25',
    price: '$55.55',
    specs: {
      color: 'red',
      available: false
    }
  }],
  [{
    title: 'title3',
    image: 'https://placehold.it/25x25',
    price: '$55.55',
    specs: {
      available: true,
      test: true
    }
  }]
];

/* table header */
const head = getData.forEach(([data]) => {
 const th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerHTML = `
       <img src="${data.image}" alt="">
     <p>${data.title}</p>
     <p>${data.price}</p>
  `;
  tableHead.append(th);
});

/*
* make a Set of all specs
*/
const specs = getData.reduce((set, [data]) => {
  Object.keys(data.specs).forEach(set.add, set);
  return set;
}, new Set());


/* create a row per spec */
specs.forEach(spec => {
 const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = `<td>${spec}</td>`;
    getData.forEach(([data]) =>{
   const td = data.specs[spec] || '--';
    tr.innerHTML += `<td>${td}</td>`;
  });
  
  tableBody.append(tr);
});
```

```html
<span>example:</span>
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/It4o7M6" data-context="false"><a href="//imgur.com/a/It4o7M6"></a></blockquote>
<script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>




<table class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="js-th"></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="js-tb"></tbody>
</table>
```

Like in your example spec available: false will result in '--' in the cell. If you want `false` in the cell instead you need to change the line

```
const td = data.specs[spec] || '--';
```

by

```
const td = Object.keys(data.specs).includes(spec) ? data.specs[spec] : '--';
```

Note that it looks like there is an error in your example. Shouldn't be `true` in the cell D4 ?